# Why doesn't OnItemSelectedListener switch by view ID work to find the selected spinner?

Tags: android, view, spinner

I have OnItemSelectedListener class and the problem is that now when i go and select item from spinner1, it doesn't show toaster text it's supposed to show. Toast text is there just to see if the listener works and it doesn't. I have two spinners and i'm trying to get selected items from both spinners for individual variables. Any help is appreciated here, i've been stuck with this for couple hours.

I've used that switch technique on buttonlisteners and it worked fine, but they are on my main class, the activity class, im not sure if it depend on that and how to fix that if it does

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

    View v = parent.getSelectedView();
    switch (view.getId()) {

    case R.id.spinner1:
        Toast.makeText( parent.getContext(),
                "Selected item is " + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case R.id.spinner2:
        //Code here
        break;
    default:
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), view.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You seem to think that "parent" is the activity containing the Spinner, and "view" is the  Spinner. They're actually not. "parent" is the ListView or SpinnerView. "view" is the individual list item.

So, you'd want to use

```
switch (parent.getId())
```

to check the ID of the spinner containing the item that was just selected.

Comment: You know how sometimes you just think things too much. I feel so stupid for not realizing this. That whole View thing, i don't remember what i was going for with it. Anyways, first time relying on asking for help here and you provided me with answer in less than 10 minutes, i could hug you. Now i shall be able to proceed, thank you

Comment: It's the documentation. You look it up and it never actually *says* "parent" is the listview... you have to derive it from the fact that parent is of type AdapterView<?>. ListView is an AdapterView? I was supposed to know that?